# How to use "lambda" as input inside of a class

Tags: python, numpy, class, dynamic

I want to use `lambda` as an input for a class function named `Integrator`. Inside of the `Integrator` class, the object should be called based on the current state. I do not know how to introduce these objects to the `Integrator` class.
Could you please tell me how can I call a created object inside of another class?
Here is the main simulation program:

```
# create LJ force object
lj_object = LennardJones(self.sigma, self.epsilon, self.compmethod, self.r_cut, self.box_len)

# create spring force object
sp_object = InterMolecularForce (self.oh_len, self.k_b, self.tet_eq, self.k_tet)

# create Integrator object
integrator_object = Integrator (O_mass, H_mass)

for i in range (grid.shape[0]-1) :

        timespan = (grid [i], grid [i+1])                       

        lj_force =lj_object (new_postate)

        sp_force = sp_object(new_postate)

        new_postate[i+1], new_velocity[i+1] = integrator_object (new_postate, new_velocity, lambda new_postate: lj_object (new_postate) + sp_object(new_postate), timespan)

return new_postate, new_velocity
```

The integrator is :

```
# calculate half step momenta
momenta_half_step = diag_mass * velocity + (force * (timespan[1] - timespan[0]) / 2)
position_full_step = posate + (timespan[1] - timespan[0]) * np.dot (inv(mass_matrix), momenta_half_step) 

# calculate forces
lj_force = lj_object (position_full_step)
spring_force = sp_object(position_full_step)
force = lj_force + spring_force

momenta_full_step = momenta_half_step + ( timespan[1] - timespan[0] ) * force / 2
```

Comment: I find this question is hard to understand because the code tells us about what your code is doing: the question does not explain clearly what you want it to do. Is the question *How do I pass a lambda function into a class method?*

Comment: yes. How do I pass a lambda function into a class method?

Comment: Aren't you already passing when calling `integrator_object`?

Answer (score 0):

I have a strong feeling that I have missed the point here. But without attempting any of the complex applied mathematics your code is doing, here is a simple, bare-bones approach to passing a function defined in a lambda statement and passing it to a class to use.

```
class Operation:
    def __init__(self, operator):
        self.operator = operator
    def compute(self, *operands):
        return self.operator(operands[0], operands[1])


>>> addition=Operation(operator=lambda a,b: a+b)
>>> multiplication=Operation(operator=lambda a,b: a*b)
>>> addition.compute(3,5)
8
>>> multiplication.compute(3,5)
15
```

This is deliberately simplified and contrived: it does no type checking, it neither handles nor rejects operators that are not dyadic, and all in all it is not very useful. Its only purpose is to show how to call the function that was passed into the class, which seems to be the fundamental point of your question.